# Use `cp src/* des/` suppressing warning when encountering folders

Tags: cp

How can I use `cp src/* des/` for copying all files which are not directories and without receiving the warning 
`cp: <my_dir> is a directory (not copied).`?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I do not want to copy file recursively, just have the exact behaviour of `cp src/* des/` but without the warning message

Comment: Oh, then you just use `cp src/* des/ 2>/dev/null` and send the standard error to null rather than seeing it in the terminal. Read more about it here http://www.learnlinux.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch01s04.html in the ***stderr*** section.